# App Engine Standard uses Java 8 despite Java 7 being specified

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I've created a brand new Maven-based App Engine Standard Java application, using the [Google Cloud Eclipse extension](https://cloud.google.com/eclipse/docs/quickstart).

[image: Hello world template]

But, when I run/debug the application in Eclipse it always uses Java 8. At the time of writing, the App Engine Standard environment requires Java 7.

[image: run_debug]
[image: web page]
[image: console]

This is despite the fact that a) I have installed Java 7 and set it as the default JVM (as JAVA_HOME)

[image: terminal]

b) Set Java 1.7 to be the default for the project (and workspace).
[image: eclipse]

c) The pom.xml file explicitly states that Java 1.7 should be used.
[image: pom]

It will use Java 1.7 if I run Maven on the command line (i.e. `mvn appengine:run`) but the downside of using this approach is that it doesn't seem to hot swap JSP changes, meaning I need to redeploy the app in order to see the changes.

Does anyone know if it's possible to configure Eclipse to use Java 7 when running Maven-based App Engine Standard apps?

Answer (score 0):

This has been fixed in the latest version of the [Google Cloud Tools](https://developers.google.com/eclipse/) plugin. After updating the plugin I found that the "Debug on App Engine" option was greyed out. This can be fixed by:

1. Opening the project settings.
2. Going to **Project Facets**.
3. Selecting **App Engine Java Standard Environment**.

[image: Project facets]